# Variable Link in Mobile Site using PDO

Tags: php, jquery, mobile

I'm building a mobile version of my site. In the desktop version I have variable links like example.com/mybq-access-txt.php?id=200. How can I implement this in my mobile site?

This is what I have tried:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
          foreach($db->query('SELECT id,username,tag,message,timestamp,date FROM mybq_post_txt_main WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() ORDER by rand() LIMIT 1') as $row) {
    echo "<a href='#mybq-access-txt?id=$row[id]'>New Text</a>";
    }
```

It does not even load any page (just stays there).

## mybq-access-txt is the mobile equivalent of mybq-access-txt.php

Answer (score -1):

You get in url exactly what you expect? Looks like you have an error in syntax.

```
echo "<a href='#mybq-access-txt?id=$row[id]'>New Text</a>";
```

try:

```
echo "<a href='#mybq-access-txt?id={$row['id']}'>New Text</a>";
```